# prevent file upload renaming for each node

Tags: 7, nodes, ubercart, files

I would like to re-use some pdf files that doesn't change for my product content type and avoid to have by example:

node/product01-> product-datasheet-01.pdf

node/product02-> product-datasheet-02.pdf
...

but instead:

node/product01->|

```
                  | --> product-datasheet.pdf
```

node/product02->|

Already tried "File (Field) Paths" and "File (Field) Paths" modules but doesn't really fit on my needs because they works on single node.

Conf: D7+Ubercart3

thanks!
LS

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for:

### [filefield_sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources)

> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

[image: filefield sources ui]

Comment: That's it !!! but was a bit tricky.. many thanks ;)